# Computer is on, but no display, stuck on DRAM

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

Today, I was reseating my GPU (Radeon RX Vega 56) after having to readjust a component in the pcie slot under it. I reconnected everything turned on the PC and nothing. LEDs and Fans boot up, but no display and the mother board (B450 aorus M) is stuck on DRAM light. When I hold power button it doesn't power down, but the light moves to CPU, and the GPU fans turn off. I don't know if both of my bios units are corrupt or where to go, help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Clear CMOS, reseat everything you can (PCIe cards and RAM), try again